# What's wrong with this "proof" of time complexity? Traversing a $n \times n$ matrix in $O(n)$

Tags: computer-science

Claim: I can traverse an $n \times n$ matrix in $O(n)$.

*"Proof"*: Clearly, this is true for $n=1$. Now suppose this is true for $n-1$.
Then given an $n \times n$ matrix, traverse the upper left $(n-1)\times(n-1)$
matrix in $O(n-1)$ time, and then the remaining row and column in $O(2n)$ time.
This gives $O(n-1) + O(2n) = O(n)$ time.

What's wrong with this?

Comment: $n=1$ is not the true base case!

Comment: That is not true for $n=1$ because that isn't even a condition on $n$, the formula you want to prove in not generalized in the variable $n$.

Think about the affirmation that you are proving for n=1; you state that the time to transverse a matrix is bounded by c n for some real c as n-> infinity when n=1?

Comment: The idea of "big O" notation doesn't make sense without a parameter to vary. If you have a matrix of fixed size, what does it mean to "grow with $n$" anymore? Try proving you can traverse a list in constant time with a similar method, if that makes the idea more clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You take a turn for the worst at the first statement.

It just so happens that $n=1$ is the only positive integer for which $n^2=n$.  Now that you've seeded our thinking with plausible deniability -- it sure *looks* like it's $O(n)$ for $n=1$ -- you then run with it in the rest of the proof.

Comment: It doesn't event make sense to speak of $O(n)$ when $n = 1$, since the big-O notation expresses the asymptotic behaviour when $n \rightarrow \infty$.

Comment: Of course!  I didn't say it made sense.  But that's where the "old switcheroo" was made that derails the proof.

Comment: To add: the switcharoo is more apparent if you look at the case of $n=2$ as the base case. We can claim that we traverse this is $O(2n)$. Clearly, that's the slight of hand.